# SAPUI5 : Process Flow control is not working on different language setting

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5, preload

I have a process flow controller which is working fine in default URL (without any language is mentioned) or mentioned as EN

```
?sap-client=001&sap-ui-language=EN#/PROCESSFLOW/1
```

whenever i change language parameter to any other language, process flow control is not appearing, (but my JSON data is bound to the model)

What can be the problem ?

here is my index.html;

```
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js" 
id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
data-sap-ui-language="en"
data-sap-ui-preload="async"
data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.suite.ui.commons"
data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
data-sap-ui-appCacheBuster="./"
data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"></script>
```

in chrome i can see sometimes library-preload error is occurring. Thanks a lot!
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYJrm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright my fault  i found the issue. something related to language specific backend customisation.